# Return code for POSIX signals that cannot be handled

Tags: c, linux, signals, exit-code

This is regarding the application that runs on POSIX (Linux) environment. Most signals (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - signal 2, SIGINT), and few others are handled. When that is done the `exit()` system call is called from the handler with a desirable exit code.

However, there are some signals like Signal 9 and Signal 15 can't be handled.

Unfortunately, the parent process (an external script) which launches the given application needs to know and clean up some stuff if the signal 9 or 15 was the reason for termination.

Is there a predefined exit code that can be received by parent process to know the above?

The script that launches the app is a bash_script. The application itself is in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return status from `wait()` or [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) encodes the information you need.

The POSIX macros are:

- `WIFEXITED(status)` returns true if the child exited via `exit()` or one of its relatives.
- `WEXITSTATUS(status)` tells you what that exit status was (0..255).
- `WIFSIGNALED(status)` returns true if the child exited because of a signal (any signal).
- `WTERMSIG(status)` returns the signal number that killed the child.

The non-standard but common macro `WCOREDUMP(status)` tells you if the process dumped core.  You can also tell whether status reflect that the process was stopped, or continued (and what the stop signal was).

Note that signal 15 is usually SIGTERM and SIGTERM can be trapped by an application. The signals that cannot be trapped are SIGKILL (9) and SIGSTOP (17 on Mac OS X; may not be the same everywhere).

---

> The question then is if `bash` provides this info for a script.

The answer is yes, but only indirectly and not 100% unambiguously.  The status value reported by `bash` will be `128 + <signum>` for processes that terminate due to signal `<signum>`, but you can't distinguish between a process that exits with status `130`, say, and a process that was interrupted by SIGINT, aka signal 2.

Comment: I guess the question then is if bash provides this info for a script.

Comment: good answer - didn't think it was possible from alternate findings on google.

Answer (score 2):

15 (`SIGTERM`) could be caught and handled by the application, if it so chose to do so, but perhaps it does not at the moment

9 (`SIGKILL`) obviously cannot be caught by any application.

However, typically the operating system sets the exit status in such a way that the signal which terminated the process can be identified.  Normally only the lower 8 bits of the status parameter to the exit(3) function [and thus the _exit(2) system call] are copied into the `status` value returned by wait(2) to the parent process (the shell running the external script in your example).  So, that leaves `sizeof(int)-1` bytes of space in the `status` value for the OS to use to fill in other information about the terminated process.  Typically the wait(2) manual page will describe the way to interpret the wait status and thus split appart any additional information about the process termination from the status the process passed to _exit(2), IFF the process exited.

Unfortunately whether or not this extra information is made available to a script depends on how the shell executing the script might handle it.

First check your shell's manual page for details on how to interpret `$?`.

If the shell makes the whole `status` `int` value available verbatim to the script (in the `$?` variable), then it will be possible to parse apart the value and determine how and why the program exited.  Most shells don't seem to do this completely (and for various reasions, not the least of which might be standards compliance), but they do at least go far enough to make it possible to solve your query (and must, to be POSIX compatible).

Here for example I'm running the AT&T version of KSH on Mac OS X.  My ksh(1) manual page says that the exit status is 0-255 if the program just run terminated normally (where the value is presumably what was passed to _exit(2)) and 256+signum if the process was terminated by a signal (numbered "signum").   I don't know about on Linux, but on OS X bash gives a different exit status than Ksh does (with bash using the 8'th bit to represent a signal and thus only allowing 0-127 as valid exit values).  (There is discrepancy in the POSIX standard between wait(2)'s claim that 8 low-order bits of _exit(2) being available, and the shell's conversion of wait status to `$?` preserving only 7 bits.  Go figure!  Ksh's behaviour is in violation of POSIX, but it is safer, since a strictly compatible shell may not be able to distinguish between a process passing a value of 128-255 to _exit(2) and having been terminated by a signal.)

So, anyway, I start a `cat` process, then I send it a `SIGQUIT` from the terminal (by pressing ^) (I use `SIGQUIT` because there's no easy way to send `SIGTERM` from the terminal keyboard):

```
22:01 [2389] $ cat
^\Quit(coredump)
ksh: exit code: 259
```

(I have a shell `EXIT` trap defined to print $? if it is not zero, so you see it above too)

```
22:01 [2390] $ echo $?
259
```

(259 is an integer value representing the status returned by wait(2) to the shell)

```
22:02 [2391] $ bc
obase=16
259
103
^D22:03 [2392] $
```

(see that 259 has the hex value 0x0103, note that 0x0100 is 256 decimal)

```
22:03 [2392] $ signo SIGQUIT    
#define SIGQUIT 3   /* quit */
```

(I have a shell alias called `signo` that searches headers to find the number representing a symbolic signal name.  See here that 0x03 from the status value is the same number as `SIGQUIT`.)

Further exploration of the wait(2) system call, and the related macros from `<sys/wait.h>` will allow us to understand a bit more of what's going on.

In C the basic logic for decoding a wait status makes use of the macros from `<sys/wait.h>`:

```
if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                termsig = WTERMSIG(status);
        } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
                stopsig = WSTOPSIG(status);
        }
} else {
        exit_value = WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Your fragment of C code should have `if (WIFEXITES(status))` first, followed by the calculation currently in the distant `else` block, then `else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))` and its action, and `else if (WIFSTOPPED(status))`, and maybe `else if (WIFCONTINUED(status))` and maybe a final `else` though I don't know when the code would ever get to the `else` clause if you test `WIFCONTINUED(status)`.

Comment: It's interesting that the `ksh` handles the signal information differently from `bash`; it makes sense to handle it unambiguously (and its encoding does).  The question does mention a `bash` script, though...I've given you a +1 anyway; there's useful information in the answer.

Comment: Also, WIFCONTINUED() is a relatively new invention, and not present in every system, and won't be valid or useful anyway unless you use waitpid() and explicitly ask for it.  since I didn't even mention waitpid(), such needless complexity is irrelevant  :-)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible for a parent process to detect the SIGKILL or Signal 9 - given the SIGNAL occurs outside of the user space.

A suggestion would be to have your Parent Process detect whether your child process has gone away and deal with it accordingly.A Great example is seen in mysqld-safe etc.

Comment: No this isn't true.  The status code returned from `wait` or `waitpid` can be interrogated with WIFSIGNALED and if non-zero it indicates the child was killed by an unhandled signal.  The signal itself can then be determined with WTERMSIG.